# Why is Spark processing my string like a number?

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

#### Problem

Spark is reading a String value as a numeric type, throwing an exception. This value should be read as a String type as specified in my schema.

#### Inputs

The dataset I'm working with can be freely downloaded from [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/wendykan/lending-club-loan-data/downloads/lending-club-loan-data.zip) (240 MB download, 912 MB unzipped, requires a free account). I am reading from the `loan.csv` file.

#### Specifics

I am getting the exception `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "major_purchase"` even though the value `major_purchase` is a string value in column `purpose`. I have explicitly specified this column to be of type `StringType` in my schema: `StructField("purpose", StringType(), True)`.

#### Attempted solution

Code text can be found at https://pastebin.com/att6QRqy.
Or you can create a Jupyter notebook (.ipynb) with this source: https://pastebin.com/xLv3LtJa.

I am trying to read the file using code: `data = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").schema(csvSchema).load(CSV_FILE_PATH)`. I am unable to display the data, however, as I get the following exception:

```
SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 53.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 53.0 (TID 105, localhost, executor driver): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "major_purchase"
at java.text.NumberFormat.parse(NumberFormat.java:385)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVTypeCast$$anonfun$castTo$2.apply$mcF$sp(CSVInferSchema.scala:261)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVTypeCast$$anonfun$castTo$2.apply(CSVInferSchema.scala:261)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVTypeCast$$anonfun$castTo$2.apply(CSVInferSchema.scala:261)
at scala.util.Try.getOrElse(Try.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVTypeCast$.castTo(CSVInferSchema.scala:261)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVRelation$$anonfun$csvParser$3.apply(CSVRelation.scala:125)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVRelation$$anonfun$csvParser$3.apply(CSVRelation.scala:94)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(CSVFileFormat.scala:173)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(CSVFileFormat.scala:172)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:148)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:231)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:225)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I tried your code in spark-shell as well as in pyspark. **df.show** works fine. I uploaded the loan.csv on hdfs

Comment: @AnkushSingh I am running this code on a Jupyter notebook on Databricks Community Edition, could that be related to the issue?

Comment: Not sure! But your schema and code worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Do you have other StructFields in your schema, with type other than String?
I encountered the same problem in the past, and found out that the columns in my dataframe weren't given in the order I intended them to be, thus types of columns were mixed and I got a similar exceptions.

Sometimes there is a need to define the StructFields in an alphabetical order in your schema.

Comment: I do have other types, such as `StructField("member_id", FloatType(), True)`, but shouldn't the ordering be irrelevant since I'm explicitly giving the column names?